# Detect that last run of the application had crashed in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, crash

When my application start to tun, I want to know if in the last time it run, if it was crashed or was successfully closed.
Please pay attention that the application should detect it about itself and do not use an external application to check this.

How do I do that using C#?

Comment: in `Main()` enclose everything inside a `try{} catch{}` and put whatever code you need in `catch{}`, such as code to write a crash-report file or something.

Comment: you do that the same it is done with any other language... retain some external state which gets set/unset on start/normal ending. SO is not there to do your work... please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: @Yahia: It is possible that the OP simply has no good idea about how to do this. If they knew that they should use a flag and still asked the same question I 'd be with you.

Comment: @Nolanar That won't work effective, there are certain types of crash (out of memory, stackoverflow etc) that won't trigger any catch block...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The application should set a "gracefully shut down" flag on some kind of persistent storage as the last thing it does when shutting down.

When it starts up, check to see if this flag is set. If not, last time you ran you either crashed or were forcefully terminated. If it is, reset it in preparation for the current run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in Program.cs

```
#if !DEBUG
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
#endif

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new FrmMain());
```

This way you will handle all errors, you can log them or even restart application in case of critical failure and restore session for the user. Notice `#if !DEBUG` condition, without it will be hard to debug, because all unhandled exception will fall here.

Comment: the directive is not required. If you cannot debug that means you have break on exceptions turned off. Simply click Debug menu -> Exceptions and check in column Thrown on Common Language Runtime Exceptions to break on all standard exeptions.